# Set of infinite binary sequence and Cantor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

For each i ∈ N, let f_i : N → {0, 1}. Let A = {f_i : i ∈ N} and E = {n ∈ N : f_n (n) = 0}. Does there exist a f ∈ A such that E = {n ∈ N : f(n) = 1}.

I know that this question is related to set of binary sequence , but how can i answer the question it ask while relating it to Cantor's diagonal theorem?

Comment: What do you mean by "Cantor's diagonal theorem"? There is something known as "Cantor's diagonal argument" and a result known as "Cantor's theorem", but there is no "Cantor's diagonal theorem".

Comment: ya ya it's cantor's theorem. sorry for the misleading question?

Comment: I just looked through the answer and I think it’s way outside out of my syllabus but anyways thanks for helping out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Here's a table to help you understand the definitions being given.
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
i & f_i(0) & f_i(1) & f_i(2) & f_i(3) & \cdots\\
\hline
0 & \color{red}0&1&0&0&\cdots\\
1 & 1&\color{red}1&0&1\\
2 & 0&0&\color{red}1&1\\
3 & 1&0&1&\color{red}0\\
\vdots &\vdots &&&&\ddots
\end{array}
$$
For this selection of functions $f_i$, we see that $0,3 \in E$ and $1,2 \notin E$. Correspondingly, the function $f$ being described would satisfy
$$
f(0) = 1, \quad f(1) = 0, \quad f(2) = 0, \quad f(3) = 1.
$$

Comment: So to answer the question does there exist f in A, is yes right according to what you have shown?

Comment: @sipsip The answer to the question is no.

Comment: Emm don’t understand why you said no.

Comment: The function constructed in this way could not possibly be an element of $A$

Comment: alright thank you for helping out